# What are the tactics that teams and leaders use to beat cyclists from a weak team 'just' following the leader of the strong one?

Tags: tactics, cycling

On the [2020 Tour de France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Tour_de_France) there was a leader for most of the weeks: Primož Roglič. His team, Jumbo, was in control of the race most of the stages and blocked many attacks from main opponents.
However, there was this other cyclist Tadej Pogačar, whose team was 'weak' but was most of the time with Roglič. At the penultimate stage, [an individual time trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Tour_de_France,_Stage_12_to_Stage_21#Stage_20), he outperformed Roglič and made it to the first position in the overall ranking.

Long story short, Pogačar benefited from Roglič's team to keep the race 'under control' and made it all the way to the first position by following the latter whenever it was possible, and then finally performing better in the individual time trial.

In general, cycling teams are very useful to the leaders, since they allow the leader to focus on following on the attacks of the principal opponents, while having plenty of support in the rest of the time. On the other hand, leaders without a strong team tend to suffer more because they tend to need

So, in an hypothetical case of a cyclist from a weak team 'just' following the leader of a strong one, benefiting from their work, what are the tactics that teams and leaders use to beat them anyway?

Comment: I don't understand why do you say that Pogacar was following Roglic, benefiting from Roglic's team. In the mountains, you need to be very strong to stay close to the first and you don't benefit from other's work that much. See how breakaway groups, that can have 20 minutes in front, end up dismantled when they come in the mountain.

Comment: @Bebs yes and no. In the mountains, it is typical that team members go and chase the opponents of their leader when they attack, so they diminish their chances to get advantage to their leader. Also, it is common to have some group of your own cyclists ahead (in breakaway groups created in the beginning of the stage), so they can help the leader in the last part of the stage when they attack.

Comment: Agree, that's why I don't understand your question. I disagree with the assumption that Pogacar benefited from Roglic team... he was at 57 secondes before La Planche des Belles Filles. You need to be very strong on your own to maintain a such close delay. It wasn't just a poacher that benefited from other's work and happened to be there at the end, he mainly benefited from his own strength.

Comment: @Bebs of course, I absolutely agree that Pogacar could make it to the final win because he was very, very strong. Otherwise, he would have lost several minutes in certain mountain stages, which he did not. But the team Jumbo controlled the race all the time and, still, weren't able to get Pogacar away. My question, then, is about what are typical tactics on teams when an opponent "just" sticks to follow your leader. Of course you cannot do anything illegal, but what are typical tactics on this? Like attacking with several cyclists, faking some problems, etc.

Comment: OK, I understand your question now, thanks for your clarifications. The only thing I could think of is when some years there is a team time trial. I wonder if Pogacar could have won this year if there were a stage with a team time trial...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your questions, @Bebs, they helped a lot. Now I wonder if I should change anything in the question to make it more clear. Feel free to [edit] it yourself if you think on something to improve it.

Comment: Another idea I had is if it's possible that teams decline the yellow jersey competition at first so the team can relax more and don't have to chase breakaways. They don't have to keep the race under control if they don't have the yellow jersey.

Comment: @Bebs yeah, that is a good one. I have seen this by allowing some breakaways getting a big amount of minutes of advantage, so a non-dangerous cyclist gets the yellow jersey for several stages (although this can be also dangerous, like in [2006 Tour de France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Tour_de_France), where Óscar Pereiro made it to the final victory)

Comment: @Bebs I recalled this question now... Jumbo seems to have been better at this on Tour de France 2022 by using the whole team to attack Pogacar, and also take profit of this cyclist desire to catch everyone attacking.